# iOS11 - Safari and Chrome page doesn't load (nginx headers)

Tags: nginx, header, ios11

(this is not a question but a note that may be helpful)

I recently had a problem with my website and iOS11. Certain ressources (medias/css/js..) failed to load. I even had a full subdomain that wasn't loading at all, safari stayed on "*about:blank*".

I opened the developer console on Safari and the only error I had was "*Failed to load resource: The operation could not be completed. Protocol error*".

It seemed that I had a nginx syntax error on a header. 
On nginx conf I had this:

```
add_header Vary: Accept-Encoding;
```

but the correct syntax is :

```
add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
```

Desktop versions of Safari and Chrome are ok with this syntax mistake but not with iOS11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nginx virtual host don't use :

```
add_header Vary: Accept-Encoding;
```

the correct syntax is :

```
add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
```